# Assembly functions have same name with suffix ..0 and ..1

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-optimization

I'm looking at the assembly of some compiled code, and while searching for a particular function, I found two, sharing the same name:

```
000000000042da10 <my_function..0>:

000000000042dc50 <my_function..1>:
```

There is only one declaration of this function within the C code. I notice both of these functions are called in the assembly code in different places, with slightly different arguments.

This is a non-gcc compiler, but I'm not sure which (I've just been told this wasn't compiled with gcc). I know that it is compiled with maximum optimization (-O3), so I'm curious if this is the compiler optimizing for integer-constant arguments and creating the function twice, once for each time it's called.

What reason is there for two of the same function to exist within a program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm curious if this is the compiler optimizing for integer-constant arguments and creating the function twice, once for each time it's called.

Very likely.  This optimization is called **function cloning** and is one way to achieve constant propagation through function calls without inlining.  I couldn't immediately find a comprehensive reference but there are some notes at [Influencing function cloning/duplication/constant propagation in gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439890/influencing-function-cloning-duplication-constant-propagation-in-gcc/15440160#15440160).  (If you google, try searching for "function cloning compiler" or "procedure cloning compiler" as otherwise there are a lot of hits for a molecular biology concept called "functional cloning".)

Although the link above is for gcc, other compilers support this too.  The reference to `-O3` suggests that the compiler in question for you might be clang, and it certainly has such a feature.